# Updating two column values of a table giving exception

Tags: c#, database, linq, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have two columns in my database:

```
[Column]
public string Message1
{
    get
    {
        return _message1;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_message1 != value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Message1");
            _message1 = value;
        }
    }
}

[Column(CanBeNull = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
public string Message2
{
    get
    {
        return _message2;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_message2 != value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Message2");
            _message2 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

On updating both values and submiting the changes I get the folowing exception:
`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

But If I change and submit them one by one it works fine. Is it a concurrency check which is failing? How can I prevent this? Please help.

**UPDATE**

By one by one I meant is that If I change Message1 first and submit changes, then make changes to message2 and submit changes it works, but if make changes to both message1 and message2 and then submit only once it gives the above exception and submit fails.

**UPDATE**

StackTrace : The operation cannot be performed during a call to SubmitChanges
  at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.CheckNotInSubmitChanges()
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)

**UPDATE**

If I remove NotifyPropertyChanging from Message2 it works. And the change is also reflected in the db. Any idea how?

Comment: Catch it & show us the exact exception with inner exception..Also what do you mean by submitting at-once & 1-by-1..Are you using threads..Please clarify your question

Comment: Thats all the debugger says. It doesn't break or go into unhandled exception code on continuing.

Comment: `The operation cannot be performed during a call to SubmitChanges` is the exception I get. Will this help?